# Subtracting Columns in R

Tags: r, row, calculated-columns

I have two columns I am trying to subtract and put into a new one, but one of them contains values that read '#NULL!', after converting over from SPSS and excel, so R reads it as a factor and will not let me subtract. What is the easiest way to fix it knowing I have 19,000+ rows of data?

Comment: Try `na.strings='#NULL!'` in `read.table/read.csv`

Comment: ahh okay so if I have other values that I want to convert to NAs as well, would I do na.strings=c("#NULL!", "-99999", "-88888") ?

Comment: You can use a vector of values in that

Comment: Did that worked for you?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While reading the dataset using `read.table/read.csv`, we can specify the `na.strings` argument for those values that needs to be transformed to 'NA' or missing values.  So, in your dataset it would be

```
dat <- read.table('yourfile.txt', na.strings=c("#NULL!", "-99999", "-88888"),
      header=TRUE, stringsAsFactors=FALSE)
```